# Rspec for Faraday::ConnectionFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, faraday

I have following method in the code for which I need to write the spec (for rescue block). I tried few things but not getting success so that my spec will enter in the rescue block. I read about using Stubs but don't know how to use it for this case

```
 def start
    some code
  rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Faraday::TimeoutError, Faraday::SSLError => e
    message 'CONNECTION FAILED'
  end
```

I also read about gem `Webmock` but is there any way of doing it without using any extra gem

Comment: show that `some code` - you need to stub something of it to raise Faraday::Error class

Comment: the error will raise if the Internet connection is not detected and `some code` i can't share due to code privacy

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't post your real code due to privacy, there is a general advice.

Let's say you have this code:

```
def start
  SomeClass.some_method(some_params)
rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Faraday::TimeoutError, Faraday::SSLError => e
  message 'CONNECTION FAILED'
end
```

To test that the message is raised, you can do the following:

```
it 'returns "CONNECTION FAILED" message' do
  allow(SomeClass).to receive(:request_api) { raise(Faraday::ConnectionFailed) }
  # now you call `start` method and check what you want
end
```

So you just want to replace `allow(SomeClass).to receive(:some_method)` with your real classes and methods present in your method.

### Using WebMock

Using WebMock it can be achieved in several ways. The most short is:

```
it 'returns "CONNECTION FAILED" message' do
  WebMock.disable_net_connect!
  # call `start` and test your rescue block
  WebMock.allow_net_connect!
end
```